# Webpack doesn't restore index.html in dist and not to clean the files in dist and doesn't build ..css file

Tags: webpack, restore

Directory:

```
dist/
   main.hash.....js
   main.hash.....js
   main.js
node_module/
src/
  index.js
  test.js
style/
  main.scss

index.html
package-lock.json
package.json
webpack.config.js
```

My `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin  = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const { template } = require('lodash');


module.exports = {
  mode : 'none',
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'main.[contenthash].js',
    //path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'), 
    publicPath:'/',
    clean:true
  },
  plugins:[
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template:'./index.html',
      filename:'index.html',
      inject:true,
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename:'[name].[contenthash].css', 
      chunkFilename:'[id].[contenthash].css'
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules:[
      {
        test:/\.s[ac]ss$/,
        use:[MiniCssExtractPlugin,'style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  }
  
};
```

From yesterday, I set webpack5 up manually for the first time.

How can I restore the index.html file in dist? I deleted index.html manually. The reason is that the `<script src=....js>` files were in the wrong path inside the index file. I thought I made a mistake with the publicPath setting. So I deleted it because it didn't change even if I changed the setting of publicPath and rebuilt it again.

Rebuilding still does not recover the index.html file.

Can I know why the scss file is not created as a css file?

Every time I build, this message appears:

> D:\webpack_test\node_modules\webpack\lib\rules\UseEffectRulePlugin.js:53
> return data =>
> useToEffectsWithoutIdent(path, item(data));
> ^
>
> TypeError: Class constructor MiniCssExtractPlugin cannot be invoked without 'new'
>
> at D:\webpack...................

The things I've done are

1. Reset settings.
2. Try deleting modules or plugins beyond count.
3. Especially try using clean-webpack-plugin and not being able to count the change back to `output.clean:true`.

Rebuilding still does not recover the index.html file.

Can I know why the scss file is not created as a css file?